# Installation failure cannot find startupinfo

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation

Hej!
I try to install pyoptix in Windows and get this failure. After searching for the installation-failure, I cannot find a solution how to fix it. This is what I got:

```
c:\Users\XXX\Downloads\PyOptiX-master\PyOptiX-master>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 156, in main
    sources, include_dirs, library_dirs, libraries = extension_prebuild()
  File "setup.py", line 114, in extension_prebuild
    optix_lib_path = search_library(['liboptix.so'])
  File "setup.py", line 59, in search_library
    populate_ld_paths()
  File "setup.py", line 40, in populate_ld_paths
    for line in check_output_sudo_if_fails(['ldconfig', '-vNX']).decode('utf8').splitlines():
  File "setup.py", line 32, in check_output_sudo_if_fails
    return check_output(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

Comment: The GitHub page clearly says that "[o]nly Linux is supported". You can see it looking for a Linux/Unix shared library named "liboptix.so" and trying to run the Linux command `ldconfig`. Adapting this package to another Unix OS probably wouldn't be hard. As to Windows, I haven't looked into it, but I assume adapting it to Windows would be non-trivial, as is often the case.